# Error while loading xls file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, xls

I am trying to load an xls file in MATLAB. The xls file contains numerical values. I have successfully loaded and plotted the file but if I change the dimensions of the file (i.e. number of rows and number of columns) there is an error:

```
Numeric = xlsread('Test_results_new')
??? No appropriate method or public field UsedRange for class Interface.Microsoft_Excel_12.0_Object_Library._Chart.
```

Please note that when I make a change in the xls file I also make changes in the MATLAB code for number of rows and columns.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please can you provide a code example and some data, so that we can reproduce the issue.  Also, where exactly is the problem, is it in reading the file, or afterwards?

Comment: Are you reading from a particular range?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently after months of it continuously working, I found out it was because I had made a plot in the excel file, so (i think) when xlsread was called it was looking at the first sheet (the plot instead of the table) and obviously could not read it. You can specify which sheet to look at with xlsread, just type help xlsread and it will explain how